# How can i isolate each consecutive variable below "n"?

Tags: python

```
## Helper
def is_factor (n, d = 1): ## trying to see if each consecutive number below n is a factor of n.
  if (n == 1) or (n % d == 0):
    return True
  if n % d != 0:
    return False
  else:
    return is_factor (n, d + 1)

def is_prime (n, d = 2): ## trying to see if it is a prime number, once it evaluated if it is a factor
  if (d == n) or (n == 2): 
    return True
  if n % d == 0:
    return False
  else:
    return is_prime(n, d + 1)

## Main
def total_prime_factors (n):
  if n == 1:
    return 0
  if is_factor(n) == is_prime (n):
    return 1 
  else:
    return total_prime_factors (n-1)
```

Comment: for example, if i have n = 10, i want to check each, 1,2,3,...9,10, if it is a factor of 10, and it it is a factor, check if it is prime.

Comment: the function requires me to put out the number of prime factors a number (n) has. for example, if n= 3, the result would be 1, since the only prime factor is 3. if n = 10, the result would be 2, since the prime factors of 10 would be 2 and 5. just a note as well: i am not allowed to use, dictionaries, loops (for or while or others), zip, sorted, anything with sets or enumerators, slicing, indexing (square brackets), string methods, and/or lists).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sympy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjc39PZsubpAhXHQs0KHdgPAVgQFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.sympy.org%2Flatest%2Findex.html&usg=AOvVaw0JbVYuFKLzxEr8P6f0rr5a) module to list all the prime factors of a given number:

```
from sympy import primefactors

print(len(primefactors(10)))
```

Output:

```
2
```